# Why Does my Program Crash when Encountering an assignment statement to assign NULL to a pointer?

Tags: c++

This is my implementation of stack,
I want to make " *traverser " a null pointer. As soon as the assignment statement for the stated purpose is encountered, the program crashes.

```
int main() {
    ......
    STACK s(choice);
    ......
}
```

here are the header file declarations,

```
class STACK
{
    public:
        STACK();
        STACK(int);
        ~STACK();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int glance();

    protected:

    private:
        int height;
        int *base;
        int *traverser;


};
//Below is the Constructor Declaration in the .cpp file
STACK::STACK(int userIN)
{
    height = userIN;
    int *base = new int[height];
    *traverser = NULL; //Crashes over here
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't attempting to make `traverser` `NULL`, you're attempting to make the value pointed to by `traverser` `NULL`. Removing the asterisk in front of `traverser` will probably solve your issues, but without you including information about what type `traverser` actually is, it's impossible to say for sure.